# Factorization of metric space-valued maps through vector-valued Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, sobolev-spaces, metric-spaces, potential-theory

Let $(X,d,m)$ and $(Y,\rho,n)$ be metric measure spaces and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a Borel-measurable function for which there is some $y_0$ and some $p\geq 0$ such that
$$
\int_{x\in X}\,d(y_0,f(x))^p\,dn(x) <\infty.
$$

Are there known, non-trivial, conditions under which $f$ factors in the following manner:

- There exists some Borel measurable $f_1:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  whose components belong to the [Hajłasz-Sobolev](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ehajlasz/OriginalPublications/Hajlasz-Sobolev-PotAnal-5-1996-403-415.pdf) space $W_1^s(X)$.
- There is a Lipschitz function $f_2:f_1(X)\rightarrow Y$ *(which need not be Lipschitz on the entire  $\mathbb{R}^n$; here this is interesting if $f_1$ is not continuous and $X$ is non-compact)*
  $$
  f(x) = f_2\circ f_1(x)\qquad (\forall x \in X)?
  $$

I would also be interested in the ``simplest case'' where $X$ and $Y$ are Riemannian manifolds with $X$ a closed manifold, and $m$ and $n$ are the measures induced by their volume forms.

---

**Bonus Question:** If yes, then can we also relate the Lipschitz constant of $f_2$ to $f$'s regularity?

Comment: Is $dn(u)$ meant to be $dn(y)$? And what does  $f$ have to do with this condition?

Comment: And is $\int_{y\in Y}$ meant to be $\int_X$?

Comment: @DirkWerner Any leads?

Comment: I feel that the follow-up and converse question may be easier: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416157/stability-of-sobolev-class