# Stability of Hajłasz-Sobolev class under post-composition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, metric-spaces, potential-theory

Informally: When is a Sobolev function, post-composed by a vector-valued function still Sobolev?

### Assumptions/Setup

Let $(X,d_X,m_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y,m_Y)$ be complete and separable metric measure spaces; abreheviated $X$ and $Y$ respectively.  Embed $Y$ isometrically into $\ell^{\infty}$.

### To define my question, let us first review some terminology.

For any $1\leq p<\infty$ define the [Sobolev class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416157/stability-of-sobolev-class) $\tilde{N}^{1,p}(X,Y)$ as consisting of all *Borel* functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ for which there exists a $0\leq g\in L^p(m_X)$, called an *upper-gradient*, such that
$$
\|f(\gamma(a))-f(\gamma(b))\|\leq \int_a^b g(\gamma(t)) \,dt,
$$
for every rectifiable $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow X$ and each $\infty<a\leq b<\infty$.  Taking the infimum over all upper-gradients of a function $f\in \tilde{N}^{1,p}(X,Y)$ we define the norm thereon by
$$
\|f\|_{1,p}:=\inf\,\|f\|_{L^p(X,m_X)}\, + \|g\|_{L^p(X,m_X)}.
$$
Define the Hajłasz-Sobolev space via the Komologorov quotient as the $N(X,Y)^{1,p}:=\tilde{N}^{1,p}(X,Y)/\sim$ where $f\sim g$ *if and only if* $\|f-g\|_{1,p}=0$.  We note that, it is known that $N^{1,p}(X,Y)$ is a Banach space if $Y$ is itself Banachian.

### Rigorous Question

Let $f\in N^{1,p}(X,Y)$ be continuous and let $g:Y\rightarrow E$ be continuous and take values in a separable Banach space $E$.  Under what conditions on $g$, $p$, on $E$ does $g\circ f\in N^{1,p}(X,E)$?

This post is related to this [earlier open question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414824/factorization-of-metric-space-valued-maps-through-vector-valued-sobolev-spaces)